# Console.BackgroundColor ставит неправильный цвет

Tags: c#

Я пытаюсь использовать `Console.BackgroundColor` для изменения заднего фона консоли на некий цвет (предположим, синий - `Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue`), а потом менять обратно на черный. Однако `Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;` ставит не черный, а синий цвет, вместо некоторых других цветов тоже ставятся неправильные цвета. В чем может быть проблема? Возможно ли ее как-то решить?

Comment: Вероятно, Вы неправильно пользуетесь свойством `Console.BackgroundColor`.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код с пояснениями того, в каких местах поведение консоли отличается от ожидаемого.